# How we can call a custom js function after loading jet-popup

Tags: wordpress, jet-engine

I am using a jet-popup from jet-engine on a WordPress site. I want to call a custom js function after the popup loads. How i can call this function after the popup loads?

Answer (score 1):

I got it

jQuery( window ).on( 'jet-popup/show-event/before-show', function () {

});